# Is this valid C? No warning about p being uninitialized

Tags: c, gcc

Compiling this code snippet with gcc (4.5) and as many -Wall, -Wextra, -Wuninitialized type flags turned on as possible gives me no warnings:

```
int main() {
    int *p = p;
    printf("p = %p\n", (void *)p);
    return 0;
}
```

But running it multiple times gives this output:

```
p = 0xbe9ff4
p = 0x550ff4
p = 0xeb1ff4
p = 0x4caff4
```

... and so on.

What's going on here?

**EDIT:** Compiling with "g++ -Wall" instead gives me warning as I'd expect:

```
In function ‘int main()’: warning: ‘p’ is used uninitialized in this function
```

Comment: Seems like you've cheated the compiler...

Comment: I've seen this before somewhere. I don't know if it's valid, but surely undefined behavior.

Comment: Calling a function that accepts a variable number of arguments without a prototype in scope is UB. Your compiler can do whatever it wants

Comment: @pmg: I think it's more about the self-initialization.

Comment: It gets better in C++: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600152/initialising-a-reference-member-with-itself-legal

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
int *p = p;
```

`p` is defined as soon as `int *p` is parsed, but the RHS is only evaluated afterwards. This statement is equivalent to

```
int * p;
p = p;
```

This is different in C++ with implicit constructors, but in plain ol' C, this is what you have. Undefined initial value.

As far as the compiler warning goes, it's a Quality Of Implementation issue. gcc isn't being "tricked", it's just being permissive.

Comment: You're right but if I split the statement into two lines as you suggest, I *do* get the warning.

Comment: So there's a gap in gcc's warning logic. File a bug report.

Comment: There is no obligation for a compiler to find all possible warnings though.

Comment: There's no obligation for it to give *any* warnings, in a legal sense. In a moral sense, however, it ought to give every warning it can. `</philosophy>`

Answer (score 2):

Valgrind gives warnings about p being uninitialized. I guess that gcc is tricked and a bug report should be filled in.

Comment: Hats off to Valgrind to actually have a test for that -- but but im not sure I would care for a gcc bug-report.....

Comment: I guess there is no reason for not to -- Im just thinking that this is too petty a corner case to to write extra code....